# Is 頭上を取る some kind of slang?

Tags: meaning, translation

[image]

I'm sorta stumbled on this meaning here. "A skill level that can touch over the top of my head"?

Comment: Context? At first glance, it looks like some sort of combat where the person has enough skill to make an attack from above the speaker.

Comment: Yes, they are ninja. The person speaking is the kid's master.

Comment: In that case, I would say the master is partially surprised and partially annoyed that the kid already has the skill to leap higher and gain the (metaphorical) strategic high ground over the master's head.

Answer (score 1):

頭上 generally means the space above the head rather than the top or surface of it.

I am not sure about this expression 頭上をとる itself, but I think it means "to move around to the space above the head of the other" in analogy to 背後をとる "to move around to the rear (of the other/enemy in fighting etc)". 背後をとる is a technical expression mainly used in areas of fight, battle or sports.